# Visualizing lower bound for the Happy Ending Problem (small cases).

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, euclidean-geometry, examples-counterexamples, ramsey-theory

I'm studying the Happy Ending Problem now, which states that

> For any positive integer $s$, any sufficiently large finite set of points in the plane in general position has a subset of $s$ points that form the vertices of a convex polygon.

Let $g(s)$ denote the minimum number of points in general position whose set must contain a convex $s-$gon. It's known that $g(s) = 2^{s-2}+1$ for $s\le 6$, but the exact value for $s>6$ is unknown. However, it has been shown that $g(s) > 2^{s-2}$ for all $s$ through an example of a set of $2^{s-2}$ points without any convex $s-$gon. I've seen the construction of this example, but I have a hard time visualizing it because it involves organizing sets of points very distant from each other recursively.

I'm looking for a geometric visualization of sets like that for small cases of $s$. It is easy to find the setting for $s = 4$ and $s = 5$ (which are as follows) in the online articles on the subject, but I was unable to find any illustration for $s\ge 6$. An example for the case $s = 7$ would satisfy me a lot.

[image]

Above, examples for $s=4$ (violet) with $4$ points for and $s=5$ (green) with $8$ points.

---

**Edit:** Going with my intuition, I have found the following set of $16$ points which *seems* to not contain any convex hexagon. There are too many polygons to check, though, despite of all the symmetries, so I'm not sure about it.

[image]

In the figure I'm using a polar grid with an angle of $\dfrac{\pi}{40}$, in case someone wants to extract the exact coordinates.

I think those examples for $4\le s\le 6$ (if the last one is correct) consisting of concentric $s$-gons are pretty neat, but my hopes for this pattern to continue are not very high.

Comment: For more on the "Happy ending theorem": https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9035 and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HappyEndProblem.html

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2542159) has a diagram for $s=7$.

Comment: A brute-force Mathematica search of all hexagons in the polar grid construction found the following convex one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEYfH.png

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you for checking it! Could you share the Mathematica commands you used so I can do future testing?

Comment: @AlmaArjuna I defined `convexQ[set_] := And @@ Table[Not@RegionMember[ConvexHullMesh[Drop[set, {i}]], set[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[set]}]` for checking if a set of points is convex, and then just filtered the hexagons by that condition: `Select[Subsets[pts, {6}], convexQ, 1]`. Possibly there is a more direct way to check for convexity; I did not look too hard.

Answer (score 2):

If you can track down a copy of the paper **"On some extremum problems in elementary geometry"** by **Erdős and Szekeres** (Ann. Univ. Sci.
Budapest. Eotvos Sect. Math. 3-4 (1961) 53-63.), they describe such a construction of $2^{n-2}$ set that is void of convex $n$-gons. It is also reprinted in "Paul Erdős: the art of counting. Selected writings". Alas, there is no visualization there in the paper but an algorithm to construct such sets. I don't have copies of these on hand, but you may try to find them. Best of luck!

**Edit.**

If I didn't implement it incorrectly, we have for $n=6$ the following $16$ points in cartesian coordinates without a convex hexagon:

```
   1      1
   2301   -459
   5305  -1210
   5306  -1208
   5307  -1201
   5308  -1170
   6592  -1639
   6593  -1630
   6594  -1628
   6595  -1567
   6596  -1565
   6597  -1558
   6938  -1812
   6939  -1764
   6940  -1755
   6941  -1753
```

Which is kind of hard to see from its plot:
[image]

And for $n=7$ the following $32$ points:

```
        1        1
    16135    -2688
    63595   -12180
    63596   -12178
    63597   -12171
    63598   -12140
    63599   -11975
    96151   -20319
    96152   -20310
    96153   -20308
    96154   -20247
    96155   -20245
    96156   -20238
    96157   -19499
    96158   -19497
    96159   -19490
    96160   -19459
   109624   -24810
   109625   -24762
   109626   -24753
   109627   -24751
   109628   -23990
   109629   -23981
   109630   -23979
   109631   -23918
   109632   -23916
   109633   -23909
   111766   -25881
   111767   -25581
   111768   -25533
   111769   -25524
   111770   -25522
```